# White corners in laptop screen

Tags: laptop, display

I have an Aspire 4752 which recently has started to show white glowing corners of the screen. Both the left top edge and bottom edge has these white corner which doesn't draw anything in that area. Following picture shows how it looks like on the screen.

[image: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_HKtO_s8ogtNUtIRTRpMmdGT0E&authuser=0]

[image]

Is it because of a bad screen data connection or does my screen is bad which needs to be replaced ?

Comment: I have a HP 530 laptop. all the 4 edges have a slightly thick white area which is completely unusable - Looking for a solution

Comment: Are those corners feel warm or hot when you touch it?

Answer (score 1):

Faulty connections always manifest themselves as vertical or horizontal bright/dark/colored lines/bands of variable width and/or flickering.

Panels which are under pressure present symptoms similar to backlight bleeding, not a totally white and unusable spot.

That seems to be a faulty panel and thus will need to be replaced.

Comment: Can some thing like this happen because of keeping the HSDPA Dongle next to my laptop ? cause i normally keep the dongle in this side.

Comment: No, that would not be the reason. Your laptop would not be affected by electromagnetic radiation at this scale. It was either physical damage or the screen is defective and that is now manifesting.